# Modify List using For loop in Python

Tags: python

I have been learning Data Analysis from [here](https://www.linkedin.com/learning/python-data-analysis-2015/using-python-lists-and-the-slicing-syntax)

In 2. Refresher: Data Containers in Python,
Under that, Using Python lists and slicing syntax, [1:43](https://www.linkedin.com/learning/python-data-analysis-2015/using-python-lists-and-the-slicing-syntax)

```
nephews = ["Huey","Dewey","Louie"]

print(nephews)

for i in range(3):
    nephews[i] = nephews[i] +  ' Duck'

print(nephews)
```

Output:

```
['Huey', 'Dewey', 'Louie']
['Huey Duck', 'Dewey Duck', 'Louie Duck']
```

How do I write a for loop to delete ' Duck' alone from the list?

```
for i in range(3):
    nephews[i] = nephews[i] -  ' Duck'
```

i don't know how to remove ' Duck' Alone

Desired Output:

```
['Huey', 'Dewey', 'Louie']
```

Comment: The code you already have shows how to modify the element at each index in a list, have you tried adapting that to your needs? What happened? There are several ways to approach this: remove `len(' Duck')` characters, include only the first word (with regex or split), ...

Comment: I would suggest looking at the [str methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) like [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace), [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) etc. Happy learning ;)

Comment: I have tried but hard in finding the right solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following:

```py
for i in range(3):
  nephews[i] = nephews[i].split()[0]

print(nephews)
```

Comment: This one worked, thanks a lot, this probably help me in removing lines from a huge dataset!

Comment: one more thing, if you add 
['Huey Duck Donald', 'Dewey Duck Donald', 'Louie Duck Donald']
how to keep only Huey Duck alone, i have modified the .split()[0,1] it ain't worked

Comment: i agree, but i need to keep ```['Huey Duck', 'Dewey Duck', 'Louie Duck']``` alone after if i modify the data from  ```['Huey Duck Donald', 'Dewey Duck Donald', 'Louie Duck Donald']```

Answer (score 0):

A slight enhancement on the above code, using list comprehension,

```
new_nephews=[nephews[i].split(" ")[0] for i in range(3)]
```

Comment: if you add ```['Huey Duck Donald', 'Dewey Duck Donald', 'Louie Duck Donald']``` how to keep only ```['Huey Duck', 'Dewey Duck', 'Louie Duck']``` alone, i have modified the .split(" ")[0,1], can you explain how do i do that?

Comment: `nephews = ['Huey Duck Donald', 'Dewey Duck Donald', 'Louie Duck Donald']`
`new_nephews=[]`
`for i in nephews:`
    `y=i.split()`
   ` new_nephews.append(y[0]+" "+y[1])`
`print (new_nephews)`

Please try this.

Comment: Hey but! this one tries to print 3 times the output, but not the single time